# Why we use a monoid and a functor there?

Tags: haskell, functor, monoids

I'm new in Haskell.
I can't figure out why we use a monoid and `instance Functor Matrix` in the code bellow and how `instance Functor Matrix` works?

```
instance Functor Matrix where
    fmap f (M n m v) = M n m $ fmap (fmap f) v

instance Num a => Num (Matrix a) where
    fromInteger = M 1 1 . V.singleton . V.singleton . fromInteger
    negate = fmap negate
    (+) = add
    (*) = mult
    abs = fmap abs
    signum = fmap signum

scalarMult :: Num a => a -> Matrix a -> Matrix a
    scalarMult = fmap . (*)
```

I know that the functor is necessary for `negate`, `(*)`, `abs`, `signum`, but I need a detailed explanation. Help me, please.

Comment: Please show the definition of `Matrix`. I can guess roughly how it looks, but having all the details right is useful for giving better examples.

Comment: There is no monoid in that code. Clarify what you mean. Also, please include the data/type declaration for what you use as `Matrix` (or link to the library you've taken them from).

Comment: `import Data.Monoid
import Prelude`

Comment: @dmitryvodop There is no `Matrix` type defined in either `Data.Monoid` or `Prelude` (which is unnecessary to import on its own, it gets imported automatically).  Where is `Matrix` defined?

Comment: @leftaroundabout I examine this code: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/matrix-0.2.1/docs/src/Data-Matrix.html

Comment: @bheklilr Here is the full code: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/matrix-0.2.1/docs/src/Data-Matrix.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Functor`s are a very simple thing that have a complicated name.  Simply put, `Functor`s are containers that you can map a function over its values, via the `fmap` function.  Lists are the most familiar `Functor`, since `fmap` is just `map`.  Other `Functor`s include `Maybe`, `IO`, and `Either a`.

In this snippet you're defining `Matrix` to be a `Functor`, so you're telling the compiler that `Matrix` is a container that it can map functions over.  For the purposes of this question, `fmap` is used to define several of the functions in the `Num` typeclass.  It is pretty easy to see how this works (assuming there is a `fromList :: [[a]] -> Matrix a` function):

```
> fmap id $ fromList [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
fromList [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
> fmap (+1) $ fromList [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
fromList [[2, 3], [4, 5]]
> fmap show $ fromList [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
fromList [["1", "2"], ["3", "4"]]
```

For other `Functor`s:

```
> fmap (+1) [1, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 4]
> fmap (*10) (Just 1)
Just 10
> fmap (*10) Nothing
Nothing
```

---

As for why `Data.Monoid` is imported in the source for `Data.Matrix`, it is solely because of the function

```
-- | Display a matrix as a 'String' using the 'Show' instance of its elements.
prettyMatrix :: Show a => Matrix a -> String
prettyMatrix m@(M _ _ v) = unlines
 [ "( " <> unwords (fmap (\j -> fill mx $ show $ m ! (i,j)) [1..ncols m]) <> " )" | i <- [1..nrows m] ]
 where
  mx = V.maximum $ fmap (V.maximum . fmap (length . show)) v
  fill k str = replicate (k - length str) ' ' ++ str
```

Where the author has opted to use `<>` instead of `++` for concatenating strings together, a rather mundane use of the list `Monoid`.  It has no relevance at all to the `Matrix` type.

Comment: Thank you, the great explanation, now all is clear! By the way, instead of `<>` we could write `++` and it would be the same meaning?

Comment: @dmitryvodop If you look at the source of [`Data.Monoid`](http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.4.2/20130829-168/base/src/Data-Monoid.html), you'll see that `(<>) = mappend`, and for `instance Monoid [a]`, `mappend = (++)` and `mempty = []`.  With optimizations enabled the compiler should be capable of inlining it entirely down to `++`, since `<>` is inlined and simple typeclasses are trivial to inline.  So quite literally, `(<>) === mappend === (++)`.